# JavaScript, anonymous vs direct function call

Tags: javascript, ajax

In the following snippet I am assigning anonymous function to **onreadystatechange** variable and everything works fine, but if I assign a named function to this variable it does not work.

```
 <script language="Javascript">
    function postRequest(strURL) 
    {
        var xmlHttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) // Mozilla, Safari, ...
            var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        else if (window.ActiveXObject) // IE
            var xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        xmlHttp.open('POST', strURL, true);
        xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
        {
            alert("you are in anonymous");
        }
        xmlHttp.send(strURL);
    }
</script>
```

The above code works but the following does not. The function `foo()` does not get called:

```
 <script language="Javascript">
    function foo()
    {
        alert("you are in foo");
    }
    /*----------------------------------------------*/
    function postRequest(strURL) 
    {
        var xmlHttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) // Mozilla, Safari, ...
            var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        else if (window.ActiveXObject) // IE
            var xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        xmlHttp.open('POST', strURL, true);
        xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = foo; 
        xmlHttp.send(strURL);
    }
</script>
```

Why is that?

Comment: Should work. Did anything else change? http://jsfiddle.net/yxgfqz47/

Comment: What does "does not work" mean?  That doesn't help us help you.  Do you see any errors in your console?  What does it do compared to what you expect?

Comment: P.S. `<script language="Javascript">` is deprecated.  Use `<script type="text/javascript">` or in HTML5, just `<script>`.

Comment: I'd recommend not re declaring xmlHttp. Call it once with var and remove var for the other declarations.

Comment: The question describes the problem. *"...function foo() does not get called"*.

Comment: @squint: Yes, but I'm almost 100% sure the solution will be found in his error console.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: I'm certain you're right, but only if this isn't the actual code. Given what's above, there'll be no error introduced. I voted to close.

Answer (score -1):

The issue was resolved. var **xmlHttp** had to be global. Although I am not using **xmlHttp** in foo(), maybe it is needed internally by **xmlHttp** object! Anybody knows why? Anyway this issue is resolved for me. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but this is the wrong explanation for the code you showed in your question.  It doesn't matter whether the `xmlHttp` variable is local or global.  There must be something else going on in your implementation besides the code you actually posted.